# How to deploy a dll file(s) into IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll, iis-7

I need help on how to deploy a dll file into IIS. I searched on the internet but no luck i found nothing similar to my problem. I can able to publish and deploy an ASP.net into IIS but what I need is a single dll file and deploy to IIS.

Is it possible to deploy an dll file only into IIS? If yes, please share an information on how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No its not possible to deploy single dll on IIS you have to copy manually and paste at IIS deployment

Comment: A single dll is not even a valid ASP.NET application, so no wonder you found nothing.